# Как я могу увидеть фон блока, если его перекрывает другой блок

Tags: html, css

Проблема очень интересная, у меня есть блок с анимацией (wrapper), в этом блоке находится другой блок (form-container) с черным фоном, мне необходимо, чтоб кнопка, лежащая внутри формы была прозрачной и в ней был виден фон блока wrapper (то есть та самая анимация). Но их уже разделяет другой блок с темным фоном...
Подскажите как это сделать?
Фон кнопки должен отображать фон блока wrapper. HEEELP ME

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 50vh;
    /* display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
    border: 3px solid #00ffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #00a6bc;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0ef, #c800ff,
            #0ef,
            #c800ff);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    transition: background-position 100s ease;
    animation: rotateColors 10s linear infinite;
}

.form-container {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 43% 0, 77% 100%, 0% 100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #081b29;
}

.inp {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}


.submit {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 288px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class='form-container'>
            <form action="" class="form">
                <h1 class="title">SomeSeries</h1>
                <div class="inp">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="input" placeholder="Логин">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="inp">
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" class="input" placeholder="Пароль">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <button class="submit">Авторизироваться</button>
                <p class="footer">Нет аккаунта? <a href="#" class="link">Зарегистрироваться</a></p>
            </form>


            <div class="banner">
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="para" id="head1">Добро пожаловать!</p>
                    <p class="para" id="head2">SomeSeries - ваш проводник</p>
                    <p class="para" id="head3">По миру кино и сериалов</p>
                    <p class="para" id="head4">Начнём!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: вы ж всё равно уже надрезали форм-контейнер с `clip-path`, дык и дырку для кнопки прорежьте :3 будь эта фигура фоном не форм-конт"а, а врапера, возможно `mix-blend-mode: lighten` и помог бы, но так не хочет...

Comment: @puffleeck, К сожалению, с помощью clip-path нельзя вырезать область внутри блока... Есть ли какие-то еще способы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301520/Как-сделать-часть-блока-прозрачным